# How Do I Enable MDAC in 2008 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008

How Do I Enable MDAC in 2008 server?

Comment: MDAC is client software - why do you want to install this on a server?

Comment: This is an app server that will access SQL and is required by the app it is a UPS connect ship server

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the StackOverflow question ["How to re-install MDAC on SQL server 2008?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302251/how-to-re-install-mdac-on-sql-server-2008)

Comment: That article doesn't really help answer what Kam is asking.